# MS Access SQL Unequal join for 3 or more tables

Tags: ms-access, join, multiple-tables

I'm thinking of switching to using temp tables and vba.

I want to do this.  I have multiple tables, in these tables may or may not have fields with items that have a one to many or one to one relationship.  I know what those relationships are (and will create multiple queries accordingly).  What I'm hunting for is each value that DOES NOT EXIST in every other table.  To make an example:

Say we have 3 single column tables, table 1 is {x, y, z}, table 2 is {a, x, z}, and table 3 is {a,b,x,y,z}, the result will be b for t3 (yes I need to know where the error is).  Pretty much, I want to use the unequal wizard but for 3 or more tables.

I may want to look for any item that exists in some but not all other tables.  If you want to speak on that, it would be helpful, but I think that is strictly in the vba realm.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, it is agreed here that [you shouldn't use greetings or salutations in your posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276033/pointless-question-edit/276037#276037). They get in the way of us readers figuring out the actual question. I've edited them out for you this time.

Comment: last time I asked a question regarding a database it got down voted because I didn't include an example. You might want to change that here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the challenge here is the open-endedness of the problem you are trying to solve.  Varying column names, table names, and uniqueness thresholds across all tables would make it a bit more difficult.  In the way I show below, I don't think it would be the most efficient, query-wise, but would be relatively easy to script.  The following code assumes values in the tables are unique within each table.

There are 3 queries total:

qry_001_TableValues_ALL

```
SELECT Table1.MyValue, "Table1" AS Source
 FROM Table1

 UNION

 SELECT Table2.MyValue, "Table2" AS Source
 FROM Table2

 UNION SELECT Table3.MyValue, "Table3" AS Source
 FROM Table3;
```

qry_002_TableValues_Unique:

```
SELECT qry_001_TableValues_ALL.MyValue
FROM qry_001_TableValues_ALL
GROUP BY qry_001_TableValues_ALL.MyValue
HAVING (((Count(qry_001_TableValues_ALL.MyValue))=1));
```

qry_003_TableValues_UniqueWithSource:

```
SELECT  qry_002_TableValues_Unique.MyValue, qry_001_TableValues_ALL.Source
FROM    qry_002_TableValues_Unique INNER JOIN qry_001_TableValues_ALL
        ON qry_002_TableValues_Unique.MyValue = qry_001_TableValues_ALL.MyValue;
```

The first table is the one you would need to script out if columns\tables changed.  It is looking across all tables and creating a unique list of values from the specified field.  The second query looks to look up the Source table name against the original unique value query for all values which have a count of 1, post aggregation.  This means of all tables involved, there is only one instace of the values returned, and it joins against the original unique value list again to determine what the source table is.  You can script a change to the HAVING clause here to see if there are x tables which contain the value.  The final query is simply the one you run to give you the final report of the values you are looking for and where they reside.

Hope this is in the ballpark of what you are trying to do.